# How to calculate total combinations for AABB and ABBB sets?

Tags: combinatorics

Although both belong to a much broad combination of N=2 and n=4 (AAAA, ABBA, BBBB...), where order matters and repetition is allowed, both can be rearranged in different ways:

- First one: AABB, BBAA, ABAB, BABA, ABBA, BAAB (6 possible combinations)
- Second one: ABBB, BABB, BBAB, BBBA (4 possible combinations)

The first one could be seen as: "How many 2-pair of 6 can we get from 4 dices?"
The second one: "How many 3-pair of 6 can we get from 4 dices?"

Both have "pre-determined" repetitions, additional repetition isn't allowed and order matters (except A1A2A3B=A2A1A3B). Doing this manually is time consuming and would like to know an efficient approach for these type of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of sequences of length $n$ composed of $k$ $A$s and $n - k$ $B$s is $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$ since selecting which $k$ of the $n$ positions will be filled by $A$s completely determines the sequences since all of the remaining $n - k$ positions must be filled by $B$s.

Comment: I've tested a few times and works perfectly. Now what if I get something like: AABCDD. How could I use the formula for this set?

Comment: In that case, you would want to choose two of the six positions for the $A$s, one of the remaining four positions for the $B$, one of the remaining three positions for the $C$, and both of the remaining two positions for the $D$s.  $\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2} = \frac{6!}{2!4!} \cdot \frac{4!}{1!3!} \cdot \frac{3!}{1!2!} \cdot \frac{2!}{2!0!}$.  Since $0! = 1$ by definition, that expression simplifies to $\frac{6!}{2!1!1!2!}$.  See [permutations of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets).

Comment: Thank you, this was really needed to understand probability!